# Fast boot up on iMX6

Tags: boot, performance

I'm working with a development board based on Freescale i.MX6 ARM Cortex A9 processors. You can have more info about the board on this [link](http://www.congatec.com/en/products/qseven/conga-qmx6.html). The Android version I'm using is the one provided by the manufacturer which is based on Android 4.4.2 if I'm not wrong.

This will have an automotive application, which will be the Head Unit of a kind of car. At this moment, the board takes about 15-20 seconds to boot. As you know, this is unacceptable for a car infotainment system. I've developed several Android apps but this is the first time I'm playing with the internal system, and I need some help to achieve this.

My question would be, how can I make the system to boot in at least 6-8 seconds? I've tried adding this line to `build.prop`:

```
ro.config.hw_quickpoweron=true
```

But it hasn't have any effect. I've seen few manufacturers have achieved to start the system in 4 seconds.

Comment: the `fastboot` tag is wrong here. you can boot your device into fastboot mode if you want to flash the recovery or the ROM, it has nothing to do with the QuickBoot setting. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this option is present in 4.4.2.

So you want the device to be ready as soon as you enter your car and have a good power consumption. you probably want to use the "QuickBoot mode"  (not the same as fastboot mode) which doesn't really turn the device off if you choose "shutdown", but gets it into some sort of power saving mode. on my mobile phone it will be there after ~1 second.

In order to enable this feature:

1. **Enable Developer Options:** Go to device info and hit the "Build number" few times

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG: hit the build number]

   [image: IMG: until you have enabled the developer options]
2. **Enable the QuickBoot setting:** You can find this option under the "Developer options" nearly at the top.

   [image: IMG: enable the QuickBoot setting]
3. **Shut down your device:** Hit the shutdown button and wait until the device will vibrate. It's now in the power saving mode. (All apps would be disabled)
4. **Turn on the device:** Push and hold the power button, after around 1 or 2 seconds, the mobile phone should be usable again.

**Note:** I know I'm using CyanogenMod 12.1 but it's not that different and I found this feature in my stock Android 4.4 ROM too. The screenshots looks different because of a theme in place.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no QuickBoot option on stock Android when I was using Nexus 4 & 5 (Android 4.2 - Android 5.1.1), so I kind of believe this is added by vendor (including CM) instead.

Comment: I agree with Andrew. There's no Quickboot mode in stock android. Also not present in Cyanogenmod 12. It might only apply to Cyanogen OS on Oneplus One

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that, but basically it does kill all running apps and turn on airplane mode. I think this is all you can do.

Comment: @Manubhargav I found this option in Paranoid and Tesla ROM for OnePlus one as well, so it is confirmed that the feature is not specific only to COS.

Comment: By the way, as I said in my post, I am not running COS, I am running CM and the source is available. but the best thing you can do is to kill all apps and turn on airplane mode.

Comment: @Firelord Found this [xda-thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/universal-quickboot-cyanogenmod-12-0-12-t3082041) that says it is developed by Cyanogen and Oneplus. It is present in all CM _based_ roms in Oneplus One. The same thread ports Quickboot option to all devices with CM.

Comment: @Schwertspize The feature is not built-in, only present in some phones (with qualcomm?) with CM _based_ roms